# Problems executing AJAX call with Cordova App

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cordova

I'm using Cordova-plugin-qrscanner, plugin works fine but ajax call doesn't work.

Looking on the forum it seems that the problem is that the ajax call does not work within a function, but I'm not sure.

```
QRScanner.scan(displayContents);

function displayContents(err, contents){

    if(err){

    } else {

        $("body, html, .app").css('background-color', '#fff');

        $(".url").html(contents); //this works

          $.ajax({
                type:'POST',    
                url: ""+contents+"",
                dataType: "json",   
                success: function(data){ 
                $(".app").html(""+data.id+" "+data.name_surname+"");
            }
        }); 


    }
}

QRScanner.show();

QRScanner.scan(callback);
```

This meta in my html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

Answer (score 0):

verify your quotes single and sometimes doubles :

```
QRScanner.scan(displayContents);

function displayContents(err, contents){

    if(err){

    } else {

        $('body, html, .app').css('background-color', '#fff');

        $('.url').html(contents); //this works

          $.ajax({
                type:'POST',    
                url: contents,
                dataType: 'json',   
                success: function(data){ 
                $('.app').html(data.id+' '+data.name_surname);
            }
        }); 


    }
}

QRScanner.show();

QRScanner.scan(callback);
```